# Where does a Minecraft Server keep a list of online players?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I realize that when running a server, you can type /list to get a list of online players. But where does that list come from? Is there a way to access it externally? or is it stored in the .jar file itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list of online players is in the working memory of the Java process that runs the server. There is no way to access it externally, unless you are using a mod.